# Extend QGraphicsItem with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

How can I create a class that extend QGraphicsItem to define a new kind of Item?

I'm trying to do that

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Node(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = 0):
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
scene.addText("test")

scene.addItem(Node())

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "primo.py", line 15, in <module>
    scene.addItem(Node())
  File "primo.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't call QGraphicsItem constructor inside the **init** method of Node because QGraphicsItem it's an abstract class

Answer (score 6):

The solution is this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Node(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
scene.addText("test")

scene.addItem(Node())

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends always have to implement the functions boundingRect () and paint (..) if you want to display the graph on the scene. Qt Documentation says:

*To write your own graphics item, you first create a subclass of QGraphicsItem, and then start by implementing its two pure virtual public functions: boundingRect(), which returns an estimate of the area painted by the item, and paint(), which implements the actual painting. For example:*

```
 class SimpleItem : public QGraphicsItem
 {
 public:
     QRectF boundingRect() const
     {
         qreal penWidth = 1;
         return QRectF(-10 - penWidth / 2, -10 - penWidth / 2,
                       20 + penWidth, 20 + penWidth);
     }

     void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                QWidget *widget)
     {
         painter->drawRoundedRect(-10, -10, 20, 20, 5, 5);
     }
 };
```